# Copied files folder structure via usb not showing properly in Gallery (moto-g + Kitkat)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I have recently purchased and updated my mogo-g(16gb) with Kitkat. When I copied some photos, songs & videos on my mobile via USB, the files not showing properly as per their folder structure in mobile Gallery.

Please suggest if you have any solution to it (Files structure totally looks distorted in Gallery).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in Gallery app doesn't show photos in a tree structure: it just has *albums*. When you copy files in directly, it normally just puts each folder of photos in an *album* with that photo's name. When another app adds photos to the gallery, it can specify what album(s) to put it in, according to what the app knows about the picture.

If you want to browse photos by their folder structure, don't use the built-in Gallery app. There are a lot of third-party photo viewing apps on Google Play, so pick one you like and use that instead.